# Implementing bash shell getops code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I got help to create two seperate pieces of code:

FIRST - CHECKS IF THERE IS A T ARGUMENT

```
TYPE=""

while getopts "t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)  TYPE="$OPTARG"
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$TYPE" ]; then
  echo "No -t. Bye."
  exit 1 # error
else
  echo "Valid -t!"
  exit 0 # error
fi
```

SECOND - CHECKS IF T FLAG IS VALID (img, image or doc)

```
t)
    case $OPTARG in
        img|image|doc)
            TYPE="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        *)
            echo >&2 "Unsupported type..."
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
;;
```

For the life of me I can't combine the two and get them working. How can I get these scripts to play nice so I not only check if there a t argument, but also check if it is valid or not and print a message accordingly.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
TYPE=""

while getopts "t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)
            case $OPTARG in
                img|image|doc)
                    TYPE="$OPTARG"
                ;;
                *)
                    echo >&2 "Unsupported type..."
                    exit 1
                ;;
            esac
        ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$TYPE" ]; then
    echo "No -t. Bye."
    exit 1 # error
else
    echo "Valid -t!"
    exit 0 # error
fi
```